# Database backup - Split a big text file by table name

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, shell, import

I have a database backup, it's a big text file using the pattern:

```
TABLE_USER£John£32£Testing
TABLE_CAR£Ford£Ford T
TABLE_ADDRESS£123£Something£another thing£ABC
TABLE_USER£Paul£40£hello
TABLE_ADDRESS£59£Street ABC£Brazil£test
```

The records are delimited by '£', but the first position represents the table name.
I want split him by lines according with initial values each record (removing the table name):

TABLE_USER.TXT

```
John£32£Testing
Paul£40£hello
```

TABLE_ADDRESS.TXT

```
123£Something£another thing£ABC
59£Street ABC£Brazil£test
```

I would like to split using a shell script on linux. Can someone help me?
After that I will import into a Postgres database using the 'copy' command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F£ '{print substr($0,length($1FS)+1) > $1".txt"}' file
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Worked perfectly! I do not have much knowledge in script, but it's fantastic! Tks

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
while IFS='£' read -r table data;do
  echo "$data" >> "$table".TXT
done < file
```